# Running cucumber test script in parallel in different browser

Tags: testing, cucumber, selenium-grid, parallel-testing

I hava a project with many features, i want to run a test in different browser in parallel using cucumber-jvm-plugin

In my POM.XML 
i add the 2 plugins of cucumber jvm and maver surefire

i create the runnerClass and add:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
features = {....},
glue={...})
public class RunnerTest extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests{}
```

Now, i am not able to run the test
How can i run the different features in browser in parallel using cucumber-jvm or selenium grid

Comment: Have you tried this - https://github.com/temyers/cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin.

Comment: yes i tried add i also add the surefire maven

Answer (score 0):

Use this for the parallel execution using AbstractTestNg with Cucumber(Gherkin scenarios) which will run your tests in-parallel both local and remote(SauceLabs or Browserstack).

```
 @CucumberOptions(
    features = { "src/test/resources/features/vs/" },
    plugin = { "pretty", "json:target/jsonReports/cucumber-parallel.json"
            , "junit:target/junit_reports/Cucumber.xml" },
    glue = { "com.lbrands.etaf.stepdefs" },
    strict = true,
    tags = { "not @ignore", "not @wip" },
    monochrome = true)

public class RunCukesTest extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

    @DataProvider(parallel = true)
    @Override
    public Object[][] scenarios() {
        return super.scenarios();
    }

    @BeforeSuite
    public static void preTestSteps() {}

    @AfterSuite
    public void reportGenerator() {}
}
```